# Find Last Updated By and Last Update Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was told to come up with a solution for the following scenario.

I need to return the "Last Update Date" and "Last Updated By" columns based on the "EmployeeID". The query must search the Parent and all Child tables for the latest entry and return the columns grouped by ID. I'm looking for a solution without using UNION ALL to join parent and child tables and one that handles the scenario where the latest record can be entered by two different users on the same EmployeeID (Foreign or Primary key) on different tables.

E.g. Jim updated the Employee table's EmployeeID 1 today and Paul also updated the Employee_Address table for EmployeeID 1. Based on that EmployeeID 1 has two records with a last update date of today which was entered by different users.

See schema and Union ALL script where I couldn't figure out the Last Updated By part of it.

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
  EMPLOYEE_ID INT,
  NAME VARCHAR(100),
  LAST_UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(200),
  LAST_UPDATED_DT DATE
)

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_AWARD
(
  AWARD_ID INT,
  EMPLOYEE_ID INT,
  AWARD_NAME VARCHAR(100),
  LAST_UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(200),
  LAST_UPDATED_DT DATE
)

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS
(
  ADDRESS_ID INT,
  EMPLOYEE_ID INT,
  "ADDRESS" VARCHAR(100),
  LAST_UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(200),
  LAST_UPDATED_DT DATE
)


INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE
    VALUES  (1,'Paul Smith', 'GomesR', '6/22/2015'),
            (2,'Francis Jones', 'KellyR', '5/20/2013'),
            (3,'Paul Bo', 'GomesR', '11/09/2015'),
            (4,'Ed Li', 'TurnerR', '1/19/2012')


INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_AWARD
    VALUES  (10,1,'Employee of the Month', 'GomesR', '6/22/2015'),
            (20,3,'Employee of the Month', 'KellyR', '5/20/2013'),
            (30,1,'Employee of the Quater', 'GomesR', '11/09/2015'),
            (40,3,'Employee of the Month', 'TurnerR', '1/19/2012'),
            (50,2,'Employee of the Month', 'KellyR', '11/11/2011')


INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS

    VALUES  (100,1,'Address 1','GomesR', '6/25/2015'),
            (200,2,'Address 2','TurnerR', '5/28/2015'),
            (300,3,'Address 3','TurnerR', '11/20/2015'),
            (400,4,'Address 4','GomesR', '6/14/2014')



SELECT      D.EMPLOYEE_ID, Max(D.LAST_UPDATED_DT) LAST_UPDATED_DT--, D.LAST_UPDATED_BY
FROM        EMPLOYEE A

INNER JOIN  (   SELECT      EMPLOYEE_ID, LAST_UPDATED_DT, LAST_UPDATED_BY
                FROM        EMPLOYEE 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT      EMPLOYEE_ID, LAST_UPDATED_DT, LAST_UPDATED_BY
                FROM        EMPLOYEE_AWARD 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT      EMPLOYEE_ID, LAST_UPDATED_DT, LAST_UPDATED_BY
                FROM        EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS

                ) AS D

ON A.EMPLOYEE_ID = D.EMPLOYEE_ID
GROUP BY D.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return 2 rows for the same employee if on 2 different tables 2 different users updated an employee on the same day, as required.

```
select employee_id,
       last_updated_dt,
       last_updated_by
  from (select x.*,
               max(last_updated_dt) over(partition by employee_id) as max_last_updated_dt
          from (select employee_id,
                       last_updated_dt,
                       last_updated_by
                  from employee
                union all
                select employee_id,
                       last_updated_dt,
                       last_updated_by
                  from employee_award
                union all
                select employee_id,
                       last_updated_dt,
                       last_updated_by
                  from employee_address) x) x
 where last_updated_dt = max_last_updated_dt
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a4503c/1/0

You should not avoid using `union all`. The data is in three different tables so this is an appropriate application of `union all`.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to use `UNION ALL`? `JOIN`s will do your work just fine.

```
SELECT e.employee_id,
       e.last_updated_dt AS employee_update_date,
       e.last_updated_by AS employee_update_user,
       aw.last_updated_dt AS awards_update_date,
       aw.last_updated_by AS awards_update_user,
       ad.last_updated_dt AS address_update_date,
       ad.last_updated_by AS address_update_user
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN employee_awards aw ON e.employee_id = aw.employee_id
LEFT JOIN address ad ON e.employee_id = ad.employee_id
```

I've used `LEFT JOIN`s for robustness because I assume not all employees have entries in all tables.

Comment: He wants the last user who changed each employee and the date that they performed that change. And if there is a tie among 2+ users (making a change on the same day) he wants both. That doesn't have anything to do with this query. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a4503c/4/0)