# Query last update from (KEY / VALUE) type table

Tags: mysql, key-value

Below the code to create the tables

```
    CREATE TABLE `updates` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `ticket_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `updates` (`id`, `ticket_id`, `user_id`, `created_at`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, '2017-09-01 10:23:25'),
    (2, 1, 1, '2017-09-01 11:23:25'),
    (3, 1, 1, '2017-09-01 12:23:25'),
    (4, 2, 1, '2017-09-01 10:23:25'),
    (5, 2, 1, '2017-09-01 11:23:25'),
    (6, 2, 1, '2017-09-01 12:23:25');

    CREATE TABLE `updates_value` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `updates_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `meta_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `meta_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `updates_value` (`id`, `updates_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 'comment', NULL),
    (2, 1, 'status', 'open'),
    (3, 2, 'comment', NULL),
    (4, 2, 'status', 'pending'),
    (5, 3, 'comment', 'last comment ticket 1'),
    (6, 3, 'status', 'pending'),
    (7, 4, 'comment', NULL),
    (8, 4, 'status', 'open'),
    (9, 5, 'comment', NULL),
    (10, 5, 'status', 'pending'),
    (11, 6, 'comment', 'last comment ticket 2'),
    (12, 6, 'status', 'pending');


    ALTER TABLE `updates`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`);

    ALTER TABLE `updates_value`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

I have 2 tables:

```
updates
-
id     ticket_id     user_id               created_at
 1             1           1      2017-09-01 10:23:25
 2             1           1      2017-09-01 11:23:25
 3             1           1      2017-09-01 12:23:25

 4             2           1      2017-09-01 10:23:25
 5             2           1      2017-09-01 11:23:25
 6             2           1      2017-09-01 12:23:25


updates_value
-
id     update_id    meta_key               meta_value
 1             1     comment                        -
 2             1      status                     open
 3             2     comment                        -
 4             2      status                  pending
 5             3     comment    last comment ticket 1
 6             3      status                  pending

 7             4     comment                        -
 8             4      status                     open
 9             5     comment                        -
10             5      status                  pending
11             6     comment    last comment ticket 2
12             6      status                  pending
```

Now, I need to create a results list with:

1. All tickets per user
2. which show the last `comment` per status

Thus in above example, I woud like a result:

ID: 1, 5 (Ticket 1), 7, 11 (Ticket 2)

```
RESULTS
-
updates_value_id    ticket_id                  comment
               1            1                        -
               5            1    last comment ticket 1
               7            2                        -
              11            2    last comment ticket 2
```

Thanks in advance to anyone taking time to read and answer this! :)

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind how you arrive at your expected output.  What is `(1, 1)` there instead of `(3, 1)`, the latter which would be the most recent transaction for ticket 1 and user1 ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen look carefully at the statuses (although I think it should be 9,11). (Btw, does anyone ever spell your name right?)

Comment: @Strawberry Go for it :-)  ... in my opinion you leave way too much green on the table.  Grab a double shot and jump in, the water's great!

Comment: @Strawberry Hi. You are right, sorry. I added the dump.

Comment: Right about what?

Comment: @Strawberry To follow the guidelines and add a dump of an example database. That is what you meant with the link, no?

Comment: Yep, I'm right about that. :-)

Comment: @Strawberry I am looking at this example now, which I think is similar, just don't grasping it yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128877/find-last-updated-by-and-last-update-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.* FROM updates_value a LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(updates_id) as updates_id 
    FROM updates_value a
    LEFT JOIN updates b ON (a.updates_id=b.id)
    WHERE meta_key = 'status'
    GROUP BY CONCAT(ticket_id,meta_value) 
) b ON a.updates_id=b.updates_id
WHERE b.updates_id is not null and meta_key = 'comment'
```

Comment: Thanks. I added: "CONCAT(ticket_id,'-', meta_value) "